# get symbol from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I can print my data frame and see label `TSLA` but I don't know how to get that string from my variable...[image]

```
>>> t.axes
[MultiIndex(levels=[['TSLA'], [2018-07-02 00:00:00, 2018-07-03 00:00:00, 2018-07
-04 00:00:00, 2018-07-05 00:00:00, 2018-07-06 00:00:00, 2018-07-09 00:00:00, 201
8-07-10 00:00:00, 2018-07-11 00:00:00, 2018-07-12 00:00:00, 2018-07-13 00:00:00,
 2018-07-16 00:00:00, 2018-07-17 00:00:00, 2018-07-18 00:00:00, 2018-07-19 00:00
:00, 2018-07-20 00:00:00]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4
, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],
           names=['Symbol', 'Date']), Index(['Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Vo
lume'], dtype='object')]
>>>
```

Comment: `t.get_level_values(0)` or `t.get_level_values(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html#pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values)

In your case, probably

```
t.index.get_level_values(0).unique()[0]
```